# Difference of fourth powers in three ways

Tags: number-theory, perfect-powers

I'd like to find a number that's the difference of fourth powers in three ways or more. I.e.: $$k=a^4-b^4=c^4-d^4=e^4-f^4$$
Is this possible?

There seem to be plenty of examples of differences of fourth powers in two ways. The smallest:
$$300783360=133^4−59^4=158^4−134^4$$

I've checked numbers $a,b$ up to ~$10,000$ with a python script with no results.

Comment: The smallest one is $300783360=133^4-59^4=158^4-134^4$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there are infinitely many. The smallest it seems is,

$$N = 4860992489864937000960$$

and the $3$-way,

$$N =335084^4 - 296668^4= 265076^4 - 93436^4= 264047^4 - 1169^4$$

See the 2007 paper [*Quartic Diophantine Chains*](https://www.impan.pl/download/pdf/aa128-4-3) by Choudhry and Wroblewski.